What does "Forever" mean in context?
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), Peter is selling a car to a customer, and Deadpool, who is
also a salesman, falls onto a Kia Carnival that is being sold
to the customer, with Wolverine also falling onto it:

[Peter] I'll clock you out!
[Deadpool] Forever!

What does "Forever" mean in context?

For all eternity, probably.

"I'm sick of this show"?

I forget the name of the guy selling the car, but he's just told the returning customers...

Glad you gave us a second chance. And don't worry, Wade and I are a team.
(so I'll make sure you get a good deal)

...where Wade (Deadpool's "public identity") has obviously not done a good job as a car salesman. So his workmate says I'll clock you out (on the workplace timeclock) since Deadpool is obviously not working at that time.
Equally obviously (to me, at least), Deadpool's Forever! means...

You can clock me out forever! I resign from the job!


I know I'm a bit old to be enjoying movies like this, which I'm sure are primarily aimed at the teenage market. But personally I think that specific utterance is intended to be reminiscent of another exclamation common among teenagers (esp teenage girls)...

BFF!
[We'll be best friends] forever!

It's not part of my "productive vocabulary", so I can't be sure, but I suspect that at least sometimes, plain Forever! is a "truncated" version of BFF! (Because only that final term differentiates it from the much older usage BF = boyfriend, which I doubt Deadpool would ever say! :).
Because by quitting the job, Deadpool is "abandoning" his co-worker at the car sales lot, it's at least possible there's an element of...

Although I won't be working with you in future, I hope we'll always be good friends.

